# How to split a comma delimited string with embedded quoted strings?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a string and I want to split this string into an array as follows:

```
string stemp = "a,b,c,\"d,e f\",g,h";
array[0] = a
array[1] = b
array[2] = c
array[3] = d,e f
array[4] = g
array[5] = h
```

I have tried following `syntax`

```
string array[] = null;
array = stemp.split(',');
```

Comment: You're describing the [CSV format](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180). Use a [CSV parser](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+csv).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a CSV parser is probably the right solution but you can also use a regular expression:

```
var stemp = @"a,b,c,""d,e f"",g,h";
var regex = new Regex(@"^(?:""(?<item>[^""]*)""|(?<item>[^,]*))(?:,(?:""(?<item>[^""]*)""|(?<item>[^,]*)))*$");
var array = regex
  .Match(stemp)
  .Groups["item"]
  .Captures
  .Cast<Capture>()
  .Select(c => c.Value)
  .ToArray();
```

Unfortunately regular expressions tend to be incomprehensible so here are a short description of the individual parts:

```
""(?<item>[^""]*)""
```

This matches `"d,e f"`.

```
(?<item>[^,]*)
```

This matches `a` and `b` etc. Both expressions capture the relevant part to the named group `item`.

These expressions (lets call them `A` and `B`) are combined using an alternation construct and grouped using a non-capturing group:

```
(?:A|B)
```

Lets call this new expression `C`. The entire expression is then (again using a non-capturing group):

```
^C(?:,C)*$
```

Answer (score 4):

This looks like CSV - which is not so simple to parse (when taking escapes into consideration).

I suggest using a CSV parser, such as the [`TextFieldParser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) class that lives in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO` namespace.

There are many alternatives, such as [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.com/).

Comment: it is related to csharp @ Oded

Comment: @Pramod - It is a .NET assembly and can be used by _any_ .NET language.

Comment: Yes, the namespace is `VisualBasic` but doesn't make any difference, simply use the class. I think it was one of the biggest mistakes by Microsoft to call this namespace VisualBasic. If they had call it `CoolHelpers` people would use it much more, instead of re-inventing the wheel cause of this faulty namespace.